# Related rates visualization (Increasing distances)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

"A bridge goes straight across a river at a height of $60$ m. A car on the bridge travelling at $40$ m/sec passes directly over a boat travelling up the river at $15$ m/sec. Find the rate at which the distance between the car and the boat is increasing 3 seconds later."

I don't think I need help on the actual problem itself but I'm a very hard time visualizing this situation. Is is possible for someone to draw me a picture of the situation? I just need to be able to visualize what is going on here.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm no good at drawing pictures, but maybe this will help. Visualize a 3-dimensional coordinate system. The $y$-axis is the river. The bridge is parallel to the $x$-axis, but up at $z=60$. At time zero, the boat is at the origin, while the car is on the bridge, directly above the boat, at $(0,0,60)$. The car is moving to the right along the bridge at 40 m/sec, while the boat is heading up the $y$-axis at 15 m/sec.

Comment: That's the thing. I'm very skeptical this would be a 3D problem since we're only working with 2 dimensions at most. This isn't multivariable calculus or anything so I am not sure if 3D is required here.

Comment: The action is taking place in 3D, but you don't need multivariable calculus to solve it. Everything is a function of a single variable, namely, the time. You can work out the position of the car at time $t$, and the position of the boat at time $t$, and then you need a little bit of 3D geometry (actually, just two applications of 2D Pythagoras) to get a formula for the distance between them at time $t$.

Comment: I should be able to just ignore the bridge right? The position of the bridge isn't going to change so I only need to look at this as if I am looking down from above. Hence, I would get a triangle relation.

Comment: The position of the bridge doesn't change, but you can't ignore the fact that the bridge is 60 meters up from the river.

Comment: But why? The fact the car that the car is travelling at 40m/s and the ship is travelling at 15m/s should be independent of the height of the bridge. I don't need to consider the height of the bridge when I relate the speeds of the car and ship together with pythagoras right? I can just look at this from an ariel view.

Comment: Imagine the bridge being a million miles high. Then the distance between car and boat will barely change at all as they move – it will stay very close to a million miles. So the height comes into the formula for the rate of change of the distance. But, look – just write down the formula for the distance, and see for yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rendering of the scene:

[image: the scene]

The car travels at
$$
r_c(t) = (v_c t, 0, 60)
$$
(grey line), the boat at
$$
r_b(t) = (0, v_b t, 0)
$$
(light blue line). The distance (three difference vectors shown as black arrows) is
$$
d(t) = \lVert r_c(t) - r_b(t) \rVert
$$
and your task is to find $\dot{d}(t)$ for $t=3\text{s}$.

**Hint:** $\lVert (x,y,z) \rVert = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$

**Update:**

It seems the dot on the $d$ did not get enough attention.

> Find the rate at which the distance between the car and the boat is
>   increasing 3 seconds later

A rate is a measure of change. In these context it is often the time derivative.

For convenience I had used $t=0$ as the time when the car is above the boat.
But for completeness let us shift that to a time $t_0$ to be a bit more general, though it should lead to the same result.

Then we have
$$
r_c(t) = (v_c(t-t_0), 0, 60) \\
r_b(t) = (0, v_b(t-t_0), 0)
$$ 
Then the difference vector is
$$
\Delta r(t) = r_c(t) - r_b(t) = (v_c (t-t_0), -v_b(t-t_0), 60)
$$
and the length of this vector is the distance between car and boat:
$$
d(t) = \lVert \Delta r(t) \rVert
$$
Asked is for rate of change of the distance, this is the time derivative of the distance
$$
\dot{d}(t) = d'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} d(t)
$$
depending on your preference of notation.

And it is wanted 3 seconds later than the meeting time, thus
$$
\dot{d}(t_0 + 3)
$$
where I left out the physical units for the 3.

Putting everything together we get
\begin{align}
\dot{d}(t) 
&= \frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{(v_c (t-t_0))^2 + (-v_b(t-t_0))^2 + 60^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{(v_c (t-t_0))^2 + (-v_b(t-t_0))^2 + 60^2}}
(2 v_c + 2 v_b) \\
&= \frac{v_c + v_b}{\sqrt{(v_c (t-t_0))^2 + (-v_b(t-t_0))^2 + 60^2}}
\end{align}
Inserting $t = t_0 + 3$ gives
$$
\dot{d}(t_0 + 3) = \frac{v_c + v_b}{\sqrt{9(v_c^2 + v_b^2) + 60^2}}
$$

The values for $v_c$ and $v_b$ were given in the task, so there is only one calculation left to do to get the desired rate.

Comment: Ohh boy. Well this would essentially collapse down to a 2D problem though no? The height of the bridge is fixed and the only variables I care about is the ship and the car right?

Comment: @FutureMathperson Correct

Comment: It's not a 2D problem – you can't ignore the height of the bridge when calculating the distance, and then you will find that it also comes into the rate of change of the distance.

Comment: But then is question is quite simple then. It would simply be $d(3) = \sqrt{120^2 + 45^2 + 60^2} = 15\sqrt{89}$ . I would then differentiate $d(t)$ and plug in my values for $x,y,z,x',y',z'$. Since $z' = 0$, that vanishes but everything else stays. Is that the correct intuition?

Comment: You don't want $d(3)$, you want $d(t)$.

Comment: So, have you found $d(t)$, Future?

Comment: I have yes. I would simply differentiate d(t) and plug in my knowns right?

Comment: Yes. Why not do that, and post it as an answer? Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: I got it now! Thank you so much! My phone let me tag your username but I figured it out now.

Comment: IF YOU WANT TO BE SURE I SEE A COMMENT INTENDED FOR ME, YOU HAVE TO INCLUDE @Gerry IN IT.